# How to append predicted data from test loader every other one

Tags: python, for-loop, pytorch, append, conv-neural-network

I want to appended every other predicted images and real one in CNN code, but I am not sure how to implement it.

The code is as below:

```
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,
                         num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=True)
    test_pred=[] 
    test_real=[]
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in test_loader:
            x_test_batch, y_test_batch = data[0].to(device, 
                dtype=torch.float), data[1].to(device, dtype=torch.float)

            y_test_pred = model(x_test_batch)
            mse_val_loss = criterion(y_test_batch, y_test_pred, x_test_batch, mse)
            mae_val_loss = criterion(y_test_batch, y_test_pred, x_test_batch, l1loss)
            
            mse_val_losses.append(mse_val_loss.item())
            mae_val_losses.append(mae_val_loss.item())
            N_test.append(len(x_test_batch))
            
             test_pred.append(y_test_pred[::2])                        
             test_real.append(y_test_batch[::2])
```

Comment: "I want to appended every other predicted images and real one in CNN code" can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The entire code is predicting images and I want to save every other predicted images. If I remove [::2] from 'test_pred.append(y_test_pred[::2]) ' it saves all the predicted images and machine goes out of memory, To avoid out of memory error I want to save half of predicted images.

Comment: `x[::2]` will get half of `x`'s tensors, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Do you mean x_test_batch[::2]?

Comment: Yes `x_test_batch`